# Boost.Graph Reference to void

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I want to use `push_relabel_max_flow` from the Boost.Graph library.
I have already generated my graph, this is my code so far:

```
    struct EdgeProps {
        double capacity;
        double residual_capacity;
        Traits::edge_descriptor reverse;
    };

    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeProps > DirectedGraph;

    DirectedGraph g;
    std::vector<DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor> vertices;

    /* Filling the Graph with vertices and edges and saving the vertex-descriptors in "vertices" */
    //...
    //...

double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g,vertices[0],vertices[1],
                    vertex_index_map(boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g)).
                     residual_capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g)).
                      reverse_edge_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g)).
                       capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g))
                    );
```

I have problems passing the parameters. I get "**Forming reference to void**"-errors:

```
    /usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2696: error: forming reference to void
             typedef value_type& reference;
                                 ^

/usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2697: error: forming reference to void
         typedef const value_type& const_reference;
                                   ^

/usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2701: error: forming reference to void
             typename Graph::vertex_descriptor,Property,Tag> type;
                                                             ^
```

These are not all, just three of them. If you need to see every single one, please make a comment and I'll add them. 
Does anyone know how I have to pass the arguments to the function without generating a "**Reference to void**"-error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell there must be a bug in the unpacking code for the named parameters, as the following compiles cleanly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4040a22070eff5ea)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>

typedef boost::graph_traits<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> > Traits;

struct EdgeProps {
    double capacity;
    double residual_capacity;
    Traits::edge_descriptor reverse;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeProps> DirectedGraph;

int main() {
    DirectedGraph g;
    std::vector<DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor> vertices;

    /* Filling the Graph with vertices and edges and saving the vertex-descriptors in "vertices" */
    //...
    //...

    double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, vertices[0], vertices[1],
            boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g),
            boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g),
            boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g),
            boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g)
        );
}
```

You might want to report this to the library developers.

Comment: The bug has already been reported at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12038 and is fixed in the development branch (https://github.com/boostorg/graph/pull/61).

Comment: @Kundor That's cool stuff. Thanks for finding out/reporting back. And +1 for the answer there too

Answer (score 5):

Functions like `boost::capacity_map` are there to take advantage of the [named parameter idiom that the Boost Graph library provides](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/bgl_named_params.html). These functions return an instance of `bgl_named_params`, which has methods to add more named parameters. So, instead of separating parameters by commas, you separate them by dots; and for parameters after the first, no `boost::` is necessary, since they are member methods.

Your original question tried to call like this:

```
double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, vertices[0], vertices[1],
                    boost::capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g)),
                     boost::residual_capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g)),
                      boost::reverse_edge_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g)),
                       boost::vertex_index_map(boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g)));
```

Passing multiple instances of `bgl_named_params` like this is not supported: it should look like

```
double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, vertices[0], vertices[1],
                    boost::capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g)).
                     residual_capacity_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g)).
                      reverse_edge_map(boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g)));
```

The `vertex_index_map` parameter is omitted.
As long as the VertexList in your graph is std::vector (i.e. the second template parameter to `adjacency_list` is `boost::vecS`), the vertex_index property is present automatically and the default parameter should work.

However, named parameters for max flow algorithms **are not working** in the current release of Boost (1.61).
This is [Boost Issue 12038](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12038), and was [fixed in the development branch](https://github.com/boostorg/graph/commit/15872fe07002afe6249a18361ff445e2de76201b) on May 2. I can confirm that the example above works on the current development branch.

Using the 7-parameter version of the function and passing all the required maps does work, but this version doesn't support default parameters, so you'll have to specify the vertex_index map.  For instance:

```
auto capacity = boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g);
auto reverse  = boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g);
auto residcap = boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g);
auto indexmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);

double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, vertices[0], vertices[1],
                    capacity, residcap, reverse, indexmap);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I should search for any bug-reports next time before I open a question.